# Socket.io user still receiving messages after disconnection

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My code allows people to join rooms of their choice but for some reason even though their messages don't send to rooms they leave, they still receive messages from the rooms they left.

Server code:

```
socket.on('create', function (msg) {
     socket.leave(msg.currentRoom);
     socket.join(msg.room);
    
  });
```

Client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://nova.broyster.repl.co');

var message = document.getElementById("message"),
username = document.getElementById("username"),
room = document.getElementById("roomm"),
feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
pastRoom = room.value;

document.getElementById("roomSubmit").addEventListener('click', function() {
   
   socket.emit('create', {
     room: room.value,
     currentRoom: pastRoom
     });
});
```

Comment: hey Brody, what have you tried to solve the issue?

Comment: I have tried making the messages equal to the chatbox value so it wouldn't possibly be leaving the wrong room. It resulted in confirmation that the issue was somewhere else. It seems to just be joining new rooms and only sending messages to those new rooms but still receiving messages from the old rooms.

Answer (score 0):

after leave the room please disconnect the socket as well.
https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/#socket-disconnect

socket.Disconnect();

Comment: The user seems to no longer be receiving messages. That's good but I still want them to receive messages from the new room :/

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.
I was sending an event to leave and rejoin the same room because I set the variable `pastRoom` equal the the same as the future room.